# Services like Gist or Pastebin that allow pasting of images

Tags: github, pastebin

Are there any services like [Gist](http://gist.github.com) or [Pastebin](http://Pastebin.com) that allow pasting of images inline with the other content?

Comment: To put images in gist.github .md files, see [resize-image-in-the-wiki-of-github-using-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383700/resize-image-in-the-wiki-of-github-using-markdown/34482991#34482991) on SO -- awkward, but does work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JustPaste.it](https://justpaste.it/) is a free web application that has an interface that is similar to word processors like Google Docs or Microsoft WordPad. Inline images and other content can be combined together in the same document. The image description and dimensions can be edited in the **Insert/edit image** window before the image is uploaded and inserted into the document being edited. Click the red **Publish** button at the bottom of the document being edited to publish it online. After a document has been published, it can still be edited and revised by its author.

There are two different ways to save a document from JustPaste.it to your local computer.

1. Select all of the content in the document, copy/paste it into a local word processor application and save it in any format that is supported by your word processor.
2. Click the **Save as PDF** button to save the document in .pdf format.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.